# Inequality with three unknowns

Tags: calculus, optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

Consider:

\begin{equation}
\Big(e^x-1\Big)\mathbb{1}_{(x\geq0)} \leq \lambda_1+\lambda_2e^x + \lambda_3x^2
\end{equation}
where $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$, $\lambda_3$ are three unknown constants. By plotting these two functions, it seems that it is possible to find particular values for $\lambda_i$, $i=1,2,3$, such that 
\begin{equation}
\Big(e^x-1\Big)\mathbb{1}_{(x\geq0)} = \lambda_1+\lambda_2e^x + \lambda_3x^2
\end{equation}
at two particular points, i.e. $x_l<0$ and $x_r>0$ are points of tangency.

Could anyone suggest the methods needed to prove this analytically?

Comment: What exactly do you expect from the coefficients? $(λ_1,λ_2,λ_3)=(0,1,0)$ will do nicely globally. Are $x_l,x_r$ expected to be points of tangency?

Comment: @LutzL Yes indeed, $x_l$, $x_r$ are points of tangency.

Comment: So you want constants that satisfy the inequality for all $x,$ and the equality for at least one negative and one positive $x$?

Comment: @Justpassingby Yes.

Comment: @Ruth90 It seems I misinterpretated your question, do you want the curves to intersect or do they have to have the same tangents in the intersection point?

Comment: @user159517 they cannot intersect, just to have two points of tangency

Answer (score 2):

The inequality for large $x$ implies that $\lambda_2\geq1.$ The function $f(x)=\lambda_1+\lambda_3x^2$ determines a parabola centered around the $Y$ axis (where in order to cover the case $\lambda_3=0$ we temporarily agree to call a horizontal line a parabola, as well).

Thus for any given $\lambda_2\geq1$ we look for a parabola centered around the $Y$ axis that is tangent to the graph of the function

$$g(x)=\lambda_2e^x-(e^x-1)1_{(x\geq0)}$$

in at least one point to the left of the $Y$ axis and in another point to the right of it.

Such a parabola cannot exist because, being centered around the $Y$ axis, its slope on both sides of the $Y$ axis has opposite sign (or both slopes are zero); whereas the graph of $g$ always has an upward slope (except for $\lambda_2=1$ where the graph is horizontal for positive $x$).

Comment: OK, thanks. What do you think if both tangency points are positive?